# Why template class in C++ cannot be instantiated with string literal?

Tags: c++, templates, string-literals

I know that C++ forbids instantiate template neither with string literal not with `const char*` but I don't understand why. Only global variable array of `char`s or `const` array. What is the reason or breaking use case to forbid most convenient usage like `A<"A">`? [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4d6ee90a7829a07).

```
template<const char* S>
class A
{};

char a[] = "A";
const char* p = "A";

int main()
{
    A<"A"> a1; //  error: '"A"' is not a valid template argument for type 'const char*' because string literals can never be used in this context 
    A<p> a2;   // error: 'p' is not a valid template argument because 'p' is a variable, not the address of a variable
    A<a> a3;   // ok
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `A<"A"> a1;` to mean? Why would it be allowed?

Comment: what about variable `a`?

Comment: @drescherjm what about `p` it is instance of `const char*`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate why not is my question.

Comment: constexpr char* is not allowed as well

Comment: Thanks for comments. Fair answer is  "the location of string literals can't be calculated at the time of compilation, when it's needed for templates".